# How to make my primary checkbox a default option for all the checking all other check boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have made  a windows form application, and in that i have got a check box in the header of my grid view. i would like to make the main header checkbox for checking all the other check boxes.

So its like if i check the main check box https://imageshack.com/i/ippzf3rGp, **all the below check boxes should be automatically checked. And if i unchecked the main header check box, then all the below check boxes should be unchecked**. How can i do this my codes are given below:

```
public delegate void CheckBoxClickedHandler(bool state);
public class DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    bool _bChecked;
    public DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs(bool bChecked)
    {
         _bChecked = bChecked;
    }
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _bChecked; }
    }
 }

 class DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
 {
     Point checkBoxLocation;
     Size checkBoxSize;
     bool _checked = false;
     Point _cellLocation = new Point();
     System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState _cbState =
         System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
     public event CheckBoxClickedHandler OnCheckBoxClicked;

     public DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell()
     {

     }

     protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds,
            int rowIndex,
            DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
            object value,
            object formattedValue,
            string errorText,
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
            DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
            DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
     {
         base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex,
                dataGridViewElementState, value,
                formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
                advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
         Point p = new Point();
         Size s = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics,
         System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
         p.X = cellBounds.Location.X +
                (cellBounds.Width / 2) - (s.Width / 2);
         p.Y = cellBounds.Location.Y +
                (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (s.Height / 2);
         _cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
         checkBoxLocation = p;
         checkBoxSize = s;
         if (_checked)
             _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal;
         else
             _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
             CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox
                    (graphics, checkBoxLocation, _cbState);
         }

     protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
     {
         Point p = new Point(e.X + _cellLocation.X, e.Y + _cellLocation.Y);
         if (p.X >= checkBoxLocation.X && p.X <=
                checkBoxLocation.X + checkBoxSize.Width
                && p.Y >= checkBoxLocation.Y && p.Y <=
                checkBoxLocation.Y + checkBoxSize.Height)
         {
             _checked = !_checked;
             if (OnCheckBoxClicked != null)
             {
                 OnCheckBoxClicked(_checked);
                 this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
             }

         }
         base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stacy I think I have already given the answer for this question. There is a event which you can use to write the code for applying grid cell value to check or uncheck state. The method that will be called on header checkbox state changed is `OnCheckBoxClicked`. here you can apply the the all grid cell value to `_checked` parameter value  loop through. BTW, I will give u answer after 1 hour.

Comment: @Shell NO SHELL u didont gave me!!!i am sure!!! about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `OnCheckBoxClicked` event on `filter_table()` method after assigning datasource to grid.

```
private void filter_table()
{
    .... your code
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    cbHeader = (DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell)dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell;
    cbHeader.OnCheckBoxClicked += new CheckBoxClickedHandler(cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked);
}
```

and add the following method in your form (you can also add this method just after `filter_table()`)

```
private void cbHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked(bool _checked)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Give the check box column index instead of 0 in .Cells[0]
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = _checked;
    }
}
```